# Replace apostrophes with graphs parenthesis keeping the content in between using Regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to execute a Regex text replace on all the React files of an application in VS Studio Code.

Inside my files I've nominated CSS classes using the standard:

```
<div className='random_class_name'></div>
```

Now I'm moving to CSS Modules so I need to replace the apostrophes on all div tags with a graph parenthesis plus a prepend variable to obtain:

```
<div className={styles.random_class_name}></div>
```

Searching around I can just find ideas on how to replace strings between the tags but I need to keep the class name. I've tried to use a positive lookbehind on className= and select the first two apostrophes after but it didn't work out.

Comment: You need to update the question and provide a [mcve].  Show what you have tried.  In the tags, add the language this regex will be used in.  Ex. bash or Python or ...

Comment: @Nic3500 Thank you for the suggestion but it's a simple text replace operation where I have a source and a target in this case and can be reproduced on any language/tool. I've added extra info such as why I was doing this operation to give some context. As stated, the text replace is executed inside Visual Studio Code using the software regex search and replace, otherwise I would have added the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that we can likely start with an expression similar to:

```
<(.+?)className='\s*(.+?)\s*'>
```

with a replacement of:

```
<$1className={styles.$2}>
```

which might be one option.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5zTGSp/1/)